# Pattern for attaching click event handlers to links injected via dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So we are injecting HTML content via dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Any thoughts on a good pattern to attach an onclick event handler to all of the links within that injected HTML? Or, should I have logic outside of React to handle this?

Comment: Attach it to the parent element then check the event target.

Comment: @zerkms I'll have to confirm tomorrow, can you submit this as an answer? I think this is an important question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, but **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** is just for render plain html. That means that your links should redirect as all normal links do in plain HTML. 
Either way, this is what @zerkms is talking about.
e.g.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  showEvent(e) {
    console.log('the event:');
    console.log(e.target.id); //someDiv

  }
  someHtml() {
    return {__html: `<div id="someDiv" style="background-color:yellow;"> First Second </div>`}; 
  }
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.showEvent} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.someHtml()}></div>;
  }
}
```

Inside showEvent, you can verify the id and take some actions.
Hope this help.